# Large amounts of messages makes Flowable rather slow

Tags: rx-java2

I wrote a simple benchmark that keeps producing messages in a single `Flowable`. And it ran more and more slower and finally stopped giving a benchmark result. What's the inner reason for this?

Comment: How does the flow you benchmarked look like?

Comment: I write my on producer but just providing messages to a underlying single flowable. You can check it out here: [link](https://github.com/tramchamploo/buffer-slayer/blob/d600b501ef649b0affc13dc000363bcc23185154/rx/src/main/java/io/github/tramchamploo/bufferslayer/RxReporter.java#L35) The benchmark is in the same commit.

Comment: Also another question. If I called `buffer(span, timeunit, capacity)` on a flowable and then `subscribeOn` a scheduler, it seems that only buffer exceeds size limit would run on the scheduler. But the timeout ones won't, why does that happend?

Comment: I can't tell what could be the cause of the slowdown; could you try and run flight recorder to see where the time is spent? Operators with time have their own Scheduler which they emit on, in the buffer case, when the time limit is reached but size limit is triggered by the upstream's emission thread.